# External login permission cancellation in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I am using default actions in asp.net core web application for external logins. Currently I stuck with one thing. When you request to login via facebook, a facebook page loads and modal window shows up with permission approval of cancellation. Well, approval works fine, but what if I press cancel instead of continue? How to handle this request??

[image]

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#dialogresponse (That’s how this is done when you implement the server-side login flow manually. If you are using any lib/SDK to handle FB login, then that probably has something built in already for this; you have to check the relevant docs.)

Comment: @CBroe okay, that's cool! I didn't find it in documentation... but now I came to another problem. In my facebook developers account I wrote http//:localhost:98756 to my whitelist. facebook works fine, but when I click cancel I'm allways getting this url localhost:98756/signin-facebook?error=access_denied&error_code=200&error_description=Permissions%20error&error_reason=user_denied&state=CfDJ8M0XfhBi1ZlKuYjgfUYTebHXWN1pg.... 

I didn't put that signin-facebook as part of my redirect url anywhere

Comment: That is dependent on the `redirect_uri` value passed to the login dialog, and that comes from _somewhere_ inside your app.

Comment: @CBroe After I press "Login with facebook" button, ExternalLogin action just redirects to fb confiramation page, and from that point I don't understand how it works, because app doesn't stop at ant breakpoint

Comment: After the user has confirmed (or cancelled) the login dialog, they get redirected back to your app - to the address your app specified when it called the login dialog, via the `redirect_uri` parameter. And at that point, your app has to take the `code` parameter passed in the URL and exchange it for an access token.